# Generic 3D texture loading method

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, fbx

Is there anyway, using C# and XNA, to make a method that you can call on and have it load a 3D model and one to display it? (In other words a generic 3D Tmodel loading method and a generic 3D model display method). Instead of using long code for each and every 3D model? For example instead of all the long code have a method with the loading code that takes two arguements (3DModelName, fileLocation) and then have a method with all the 3D drawing code in it that takes two arguements (3DModelName, Location). Is this possible? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Yeah sorry I'll change that to Model. A 3D Model

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm completely understanding what you're asking but the following is pretty standard Xna and it's about as short and simple as you can make it.

The file location is practically irrelevant in Xna. You simply add the file (fbx or x) to the content project in the solution explorer and you don't need to concern yourself with file location in the code.

```
//in the fields section of some class
Model myModel;

//in an initialization or loadContent method of the same class
myModel = LoadMyModel(name, Content);

//load & draw methods that can be called any time as long as they are in scope
Model LoadMyModel(string name, ContentManager content)
{
  return content.Load<Model>(name);
}

void DrawModel(Model myModel, Matrix worldTransform, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
{
   myModel.Draw(worldTransform, view, projection);
}
```